How can I know what's the security authentication protocol of a wireless connection?
I need to log in my college's wireless network, but I don't know which's its authentication protocol (WEP, WPA and so on) so I can't use it at all.
I think it has an Enterprise Wireless Network, but I know almost nothing about it.
I'm using XFCE. It doesn't ask me any login dialog to use it, and that's the problem
How can I connect to this network?
At least, I need the authentication protocol to configure Network Manager (using nm-connection-editor).
It doesn't matter if another software is needed.
Thank you a lot.
I'm running Linux 6.8.0-41-lowlatency with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Ask your college's IT Department. They set it up. They will tell you if you're allowed to connect, and how to go about it.

If the answer works for you accept the answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

From the command-line: nmcli dev wifi
Find the SSID on the left and the security protocol should appear under the Security column on the far right.

Thank you a lot.
I'll test it tomorrow at college.That's what I needed :)
